# The element carrying error message showing only partially on validation

Tags: wpf, errortemplate

Here is the markup for the `TextBox` element that I seek to validate:

```
<StackPanel Margin="7">
    <Label x:Name="lblPrompt" Margin="7,12,7,5" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtInput}" />

    <TextBox x:Name="txtInput" Margin="7,0,7,7" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrTemplate}" />

    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="Auto" Margin="7,7,7,3">
        <Button x:Name="btnOK" Content="_OK" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,7,0"  Background="BlanchedAlmond" Click="btnOK_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="_Cancel" Padding="2" Margin="7,0,7,0" IsCancel="True" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Click="btnCancel_Click" />
    </UniformGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

And `TextBox's error template` is defined as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner,
                                  Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" Background="Red" Foreground="White" Margin="3,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" MinWidth="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Now, when validation fails on the `TextBox` control, the `TextBlock` element defined in the error template shows only partially. Please see this image:

[image: Application Screenshot]

Could you kindly sugggest how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

StackPanel does not limit its bounds, so wrap it into the grid (which does) in your error template and this should solve the problem.

Comment: Nope. It didn't solve the problem. Putting the StackPanel under the Grid panel produced the same output, whereas putting the controls directly under the grid caused the TextBlock element to be laid over the TextBox element.